# CreateHTMLDocument with Custom URL for the document

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to do something like this

```
let doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument();
doc.URL = url;    //can't do, doc.URL is readonly
```

Any way to set the doc.URL or doc.baseURI on the custom document as these are set to about:blank.

I want to use this document object to do doc.createelement('a') to turn relative links to absolute but it's in a background extension so I need to have a URL on the custom document to do this.

Comment: You don't know the domain to use? What should it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append a [<base> element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) inside your doc:

```js
const doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument();
const base = doc.createElement( 'base' );
base.href = "https://example-site.com/biz/foo/";
doc.head.append( base );


const a = doc.createElement( "a" );
a.href = "../bar/baz.html";
doc.body.append( a );
console.log( a.href );
```

But note that you don't need all this at all, the [`URL` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) accepts a "base" as second argument:

```js
const base = "https://example-site.com/biz/foo/"
const rel = "../bar/baz.html";
console.log( new URL( rel, base ).href );
```

Comment: In the first snippet you're totally assigning things to constants and also appending base to the head doesn't seem to work. The second URL constructor appears to be a better way and doesn't even require fiddling with the document. Thanks.

Comment: @xmxmxmx hum yes... what's bad with assigning things to constants? In my code I won't reassign these, so they are constants. And yes, appending base to `doc`'s `head` works, otherwise you wouldn't have `https://example-site.com/biz/bar/baz.html` as output in the console but `../bar/baz.html`.

Comment: The whole reason I can't do doc.URL = url is because it's readonly i.e. a constant. Constants are read only. If you assign anything to a constant it will always be an error. I checked again and you're right, assigning base to the head does work, it wasn't working because I was doing this before setting the html. I might do this afterall then. I'm accepting your answer but please do not assign things to constants 'cos the compiler will stop you if you try to do that and if it doesn't then God surely will.

Comment: ;-) no offense but I'll wait a bit before taking your advice about how to write js into consideration. If you do assign an object to `const`, you can still very well interact with this object and set its properties. (And you should rather go with the second snippet, the first one creates a whole HTMLDocument for nothing)

Comment: Strangely enough I tried it and it works. I suppose the const base is constant but it's members are not?! So the const object members are still variables. I already have the document so the first snippet works too for me. I haven't used const yet. Thanks heaps.

Comment: For anyone reading this, I checked both methods and they're almost the same in speed, the second method is slightly faster.

Comment: @xmxmxmx hum... not sure how you did your perf tests, but for me the second version is 90% faster: https://jsperf.com/base-vs-base on my machine, "URL" ran at 900,000 OPS, while "doc" ran at 21,000 OPS. But the execution speed is not even the worse difference here, we should also measure the memory usage, and once again, URL will outperform doc by magnitudes.

Comment: You included the createdocument. My document was already created so my test was comparing a large loop of the rest like doc.createelement with the URL constructor which take approximately the same time. I ended up using the URL constructor 'cos that was slightly faster in most tests.